# Suitable data type for looping through c++ vectors

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a code like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > solutions;
std::vector<double> test_vals(5);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    test_vals = getDoubleVector();
    if (/*some condition*/)
    {
        solutions.push_back(test_vals);
    }
}
```

Now when I try to iterate through the vector using this technique, it'll crash at runtime:

```
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < solutions.size(); i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)    
    {
        std::cout << solutions[i][j] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Using this line as the for condition for the inner loop also result in a crash:

```
for(std::size_t j = 0; j < solutions[i].size(); j++)
```

Only the 'proper' approach works:

```
for(std::vector<double>::size_type j = 0; j < solutions[i].size(); j++)
```

The things is, I'm a bit confused about where which data type for `j` is suitable. I've used simple `int` variables to iterate through a vector of strings and that works fine. It also works in the case of some custom data types I've used over time, so why not here? Also, in what cases is `std::size_t` suitable? In the example I have it makes sense to use the safer approach, but what if I needed to do something like this:

```
for(std::vector<double>::size_type j = 0; j < solutions[i].size(); j++)
{
    std::vector</*some other data type*/> vector2(5);
    vector2[j].double_val = solutions[i][j];
}
```

Now would I need to carry along a separate `size_type` for `vector2` or is there some way I can use `j` here too?

Comment: It is impossible that the type of `j` is the actual cause of your crash. I'd bet that there are other errors lurking in your program.

Comment: Look at the callstack of the crash/see what the actual size vector elements of the solution[i] are

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the index, you're not even using it.

```
for (const auto& solution : solutions)
{
    for (const auto& item : solution)
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I know the index can be avoided altogether (I sometimes use iterators myself). Just wanted to know the underlying mechanics.